# how to send an authentication mail using android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I created a signup page  for my app and in that it only checks if the  email pattern is correct but I  want to create a method to check if the mail really exist or if the person is using someone else mail. For that I will need to send a mail to user and verify maybe by asking to click in the link  or sending an OTP but idk how to do that
this is my code

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    ActivitySignUpBinding binding;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        progressdialog=new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
        progressdialog.setTitle("Creating Account");
        progressdialog.setMessage("please wait while we create your account");
        binding.SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressdialog.show();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(binding.Email.getText().toString()
                        ,binding.Password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        progressdialog.dismiss();
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && !binding.Username.getText().toString().equals("") ) {
                            ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings =
                                    ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                                            // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
                                            // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
                                            .setUrl("https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234")
                                            // This must be true
                                            .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
                                            .setIOSBundleId("com.example.ios")
                                            .setAndroidPackageName(
                                                    "com.example.android",
                                                    true, /* installIfNotAvailable */
                                                    "12"    /* minimumVersion */)
                                            .build();
                            String email=binding.Email.getText().toString();
                            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                            auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Log.d("TAG", "Email sent.");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            Users user=new Users(binding.Username.getText().toString(),binding.Email.getText().toString(),binding.Password.getText().toString());
                            String id=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                            String selectedOption  =  spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            database.getReference().child("Users").child(selectedOption).child(id).setValue(user);
                            Intent intent;
                            if(selectedOption.contains("Driver")){
                                intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, HomePage.class);
                            }
                            else{
                                intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, Custhomepage.class);
                            }
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                        else { //if there is error in signup
                            if(binding.Username.getText().toString().equals("")){
                                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Please enter a username",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });//to check if value match
            }
        });

    }





    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple Google search will give A LOT of examples including explanations. One of the most popular methods is using Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth

Comment: heyy @DavidLee I did read that firebase But the issue is idk where I should keep those code sniipet inside my code :/

Comment: I believe they pretty much explain everything you need. However, if you have specific parts that you don't understand, then it might be better for you to know more about Android Studio in general. Also, there other websites (i.e., blogs) that give you a "complete" step-by-step explanations.

Comment: Do you want to use the email link auth or email password auth? With email-link the email will get verified immediately.

Comment: ig email link auth is better @Dharmaraj

Comment: I've posted an answer using Email Link auth, if that was helpful you can accept/upvote so others will know this is resolved else feel free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up your own mechanism or OTP based verification, you can use [Firebase Email Link Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth) which send a link to user's email which can be used to login in existing users as well as sign up new users.

You can trigger an email by running the following code snippet:

```
ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings =
        ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
                // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
                .setUrl("https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234")
                // This must be true
                .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
                .setIOSBundleId("com.example.ios")
                .setAndroidPackageName(
                        "com.example.android",
                        true, /* installIfNotAvailable */
                        "12"    /* minimumVersion */)
                .build();


FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                }
            }
        });
```

You can read more about ActionCodeSettings [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#java_1).

> handleCodeInApp: Set to true. The sign-in operation has to always be
> completed in the app unlike other out of band email actions (password
> reset and email verifications). This is because, at the end of the
> flow, the user is expected to be signed in and their Auth state
> persisted within the app.

Just to clarify, the code snippet above goes in your button click listener. Also make sure you pass the email parameter correctly.

After your app is opened, you would need to verify the sign in link. You can do so by following the steps and code snippets given in the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#verify_link_and_sign_in).

Comment: heyy can it be inside the if task.issuccesful() cos it will be better as i wont have to face issuues of wrong mail

Comment: @MohammadYusuf yes if you have something else before in that on click listener then sure.

Comment: I tried putting this code but i didnt recieve any mail about verification

Comment: @MohammadYusuf can you share your latest code? I'd like to check if the code is reachable

Comment: yea i edited my code now check the code again